# Using a microsft natural keyboard with my macbook, how to setup the short keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

I have a microsoft natural keyboard with my macbookpro laptop.

Short cut keys don't seem be working, like when I am using chrome I can usually do:

```
control-T to open a new tab (or command-T on the laptop).
```

DO I have to configure this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>? The <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on most keyboards translates to the <kbd>Command</kbd> key on macs.

Comment: what about 'option' and 'fn' and 'control' key mappings?

Comment: <kbd>Option</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Control</kbd> is the same. <kbd>Fn</kbd> is often keyboard-specific, and may or may not have an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the correct drivers (IntelliType) from the Microsoft homepage! BTW the keyboard with foot attached fits perfectly over my Macbook 13" :)